# jQuery: Searching for data that has been commented out in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access some data on a page that is trying to keep scrapers out.

From what I gather, the page acts the following:

1.) Skeleton page loads
2.) Once that's completed, there is some javascript that access the data blob and then fills in the page with the appropriate content

The data I am trying to access looks like this

```
<code id="templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming..."><!--{"data":{"breadcrumbs": ...this is where the data is... }}--></code>
```

And the script that runs:

```
<script>if (!fs.isUniEscapeOn()) { fs.setUniEscape(true); }fs.embed('templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming...','templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming',undefined,'stream-container');</script>
```

However when I try jQuery selectors like `$('code')` or `$('code[id*="templates]')` neither of them can find the element.

Is it possible for a page to hide an element from a jQuery selector?

Any ideas on how to access the data inside the `<code >` tag?

[image]

Comment: I guess the id is messing up here try removing id and running your first jquery code line\

Comment: I'm sorry, can you clarify with an example?

Comment: make  <code><!--{"data":{"breadcrumbs": ...this is where the data is... }}--></code> and then try reading it with $('code') selecter\

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. when you say `"make **cdoe** and then try reading it with $('code')`...what am I making?

Comment: the <code> has id that is id="templates/desktop/profile/profile_streaming..."  right i believe this one is the culprit try giving a simpler id

Answer (score 1):

If the content of  `<code> </code>` is only comment,

```
$('code').contents()[0].data
```

would extract the comment from there. If the content there is a JSON you can use `JSON.parse` to get the field of you interest from the object thus obtained.

Comment: It returns an empty string. `<!----->`

Comment: Yea, must be something happening on the page to hide the results. Adding a picture to my question.

Comment: Try looking up in the developer tools if the content exists in the intended position.

Comment: yea, I looked at `stream-container` and only SOME of that data is loaded in there. It's hard to figure out where everything goes and what its called.